# SQL lite select for actual week (from monday till sunday)

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I'm trying to select values for actual week from monday to sunday in SQLlite.

I'm trying to do by this way:

```
SELECT * FROM planned_calls WHERE DATE(date) >= DATE('now', 'weekday 0', '-7 days');
```

But it return also result from past (for example today is monday but in returned result are results from last sunday too).

How can I do it right please?

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 1):

`date('now', 'weekday 0')` is the next Sunday.

Subtracting seven days goes to the previous Sunday.

If you want to start at Monday, you have to subtract six days.

Comment: Thanks! It's not quite obvious that `date('now', 'weekday 0')` is the next Sun

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
SELECT * FROM planned_calls WHERE DATE(date) > DATE('now', 'weekday 0', '-7 days');
```

Comment: It returns also result in future for example values from next month.